# How do i find which Join is taking most of the time while executing a Hibernate query?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, join

I was asked this question in an interview. Suppose you have written a hibernate query (native or HQL) and this query contains 3-4 Joins. Now the query is running slow . So if i debug how do i find out which join is taking the most time?

I have talked with my collegues , my teamMates , asked many senior developers and searched internet too but didn't got any satisfied answers.

I have come up with these two approaches:

1: You write a logging info with current timestamp at the start and end of the query so that you can check in the logs the time taken by the query.

2: Or you can integrate log4j logger with hibernate so that hibernate prints the logs in detailed format.

Is this even close to solve this? i have no clue. 
Please assist

Answer (score 0):

Neither.  You have to log in details the query, and then pass the query to your DB execution analyzer. Having a look at the query plan will give a hint on that.